# What does someone do vs what someone does?

Tags: grammar

Context: Jerry will have to think about what does he want more. vs Jerry will have to think about what he wants more.

Comment: "What does he want?" is a question. You could say "...think about the question 'What does he want?'", otherwise it has to be "about what he wants".

Comment: This is such a common duplicate, it is a shame that the system doesn't find the dupes more easily.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Kate Bunting:

- "What does he want?" is a question.
- "what he wants" -- treat it like a noun. (Example: *Jerry will have to think about what he wants more.*)
- "what he *does* want" = "what he (yes) wants," to contrast something that he doesn't want. (Example: *He doesn't want the left one, but he does want the middle one.* with a bit of intonation emphasis on "does".) The opposite of doesn't.